# Use of google service account for DFP

Tags: google-api-python-client

I am trying to use Service account for DFP but i am getting this error

> OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('asn1 encoding routines', 'ASN1_D2I_READ_BIO', 'not enough data')]

I have added service account in the dfp and checked the email_id of service account created but still not able to solve the issue

here is my code can someone please solve this for me

```
from googleads import dfp
from googleads import oauth2


import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='debug.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
# OAuth 2.0 credential information. In a real application, you'd probably be
# pulling these values from a credential storage.
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = '600632524044-6g7l2njp5g5ldd21j7eaolf1k15pdm1u@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
KEY_FILE = 'D:\DFP\GoogleDFP.p12'

# DFP API information.
APPLICATION_NAME = 'New Srevice Account'


def main(service_account_email, key_file, application_name):

    # with open(key_file, 'rb') as f:
    #   private_key = f.read()
    # f.close()
    oauth2_client = oauth2.GoogleServiceAccountClient(
    oauth2.GetAPIScope('dfp'), service_account_email, key_file)

    client = dfp.DfpClient(oauth2_client, application_name)

    inventory_service = client.GetService('InventoryService', version='v201505')
    statement = dfp.FilterStatement()

  # Get ad units by statement.
    while True:
        response = inventory_service.getAdUnitsByStatement(
        statement.ToStatement())
        if 'results' in response:
      # Display results.
            for ad_unit in response['results']:
                print ('Ad unit with ID \'%s\' and name \'%s\' was found.'
                % (ad_unit['id'], ad_unit['name']))
                statement.offset += dfp.SUGGESTED_PAGE_LIMIT
        else:
            break
  # networks = dfp_client.GetService('NetworkService').getAllNetworks()
  # for network in networks:
  #   print ('Network with network code \'%s\' and display name \'%s\' was found.'
  #          % (network['networkCode'], network['displayName']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, KEY_FILE, APPLICATION_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i got the error there is bug in googleads in the oauth2.py

The key file should be opened in binary mode 
line number 208 in oauth2.py
with open(key_file) as f:

it should be with open(key_file,'rb') as f: